# List out subcategories under parentcategory based on product

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, query-builder, laravel-5

As mentioned in the title, the problem is how to list the subcategories under the parent category based on the product. I have no problem listing out the parent category and all its subcategories as I have shown in the sample code at the end of this post. But I need to list out the subcategories based on the product.

This is the sample structure of my categories:

> ```
> Electronic
> -Computer
> -Phone
> -Gadget
>
> Grocery
> -Food
> -Drinks
> ```

**This is my products table migration:**

```
   Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->decimal('price')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**This is my categories table migration**

```
   Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this one is the **category_product** which acts as for **many to many** table between **category** and **product**:

```
    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have setup all the relationship. Here are my models:

This is my category model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

This is my product model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public function categories()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
   }
}
```

This is my ProductController.php, I'm able to display all parents category with its subcategories using this code:

```
public function show($id)
 {   
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id); 
      $categories = Category::with('children')->get();
      return view('products.show', compact('product','categories'));

 }
```

So my product.shows.blade looks like this:

```
@foreach($categories as $item)
    @if($item->children->count() > 0 )
        <li>
            {{ $item->name }}
            <ul>
                @foreach($item->children as $submenu)
                    <li>{{ $submenu->name }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endif
```

@endforeach

//OUTPUT:

```
Electronic  
 Computer
 Phone
 Gadget

Grocery
 Food
 Drinks
```

But let say that this particular product (called Product 1) has the parent category of **Electronic** and the subcategory is **Computer** and **Phone** which I already attached them in the database. This is the overview of the data from the database:

[image: products table]

[image: categories table]

[image: category_product table]

How do I display the category of Product 1 with its parent and subcategories? I want the output to be like

```
Product 1 

Category:
 Electronic
  Computer
  Phone
```

Update:

So, another thing that I have done was adding the $product->categories but the code will only list out a parent category that the Product1 has with all its subcategories. It doesn't filter the subcategories specific to the Product1

```
   @foreach($product->categories as $item)
        @if($item->children->count() > 0 )
            <li>
                {{ $item->name }}
                <ul>
                    @foreach($item->children as $submenu)
                        <li>{{ $submenu->name }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

So, instead of the output like this (which i want):

```
Category:
 Electronic
  Computer
  Phone
```

it will list out like this (which is not i want):

```
Category:
 Electronic
  Computer
  Phone
  Gadget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly like so:

Controller

```
$product = Product::with('categories.parent')->findOrFail($id);
$categories = $product->categories->groupBy('parent_id');
```

---

```
@foreach($categories as $parent_id => $children)

    @if($children->first()->parent}}

    Parent {{$children->first()->parent->name}}
    @foreach($children as $child)
         //print child
    @endforeach

    @endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: by the way, your code did not work (same code like mine). this code just listed out all the subchildren that the parent category has for example, this will list out the product1's parent category which is Electronic and all its subcategories no filtering is done. I fixed another part but I'm still looking for the solution for this. accidentally voted this answer up

Comment: what i want is to display the subcategories based on the the product. not to list all of them. any idea ? :\

Comment: Oh! You want the opposite.

Comment: I got error  trying to get property of non-object. For this updated answer, why do we need $product = Product::with('categories.parent')->findOrFail($id);

Comment: Which line? If you dd() the categories does it have the categories and presenters?

Comment: I took a guess. You have to decide what to do for categories without parents or if you want to show the parent if it's not attached too.

Comment: any category that has no parent, the parent_id is 0. that is what i thought to filter based on parents that have no category. I have already implement ed this design in the database as shown but It's confusing how do we filter that in the query.

Comment: Someone could also delete a parent and leave the children. That would break the relationship but leave I'd behind.

Comment: You can do Product::with('categories', function($query){ return $query->where('parent_id', '>', 0); })->finOrFail();